# rails2 memcache expires_in problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a strange problem with a Rails 2.3.4 application.
The expires_in time is set to 10 seconds after each hour. But memcache seems to remember the value even after a cache flush.

```
caches_action :deals, :expires_in => (3600 - Time.now.to_i % 3600) + 10,
  :cache_path => Proc.new { |controller| "blah" }
```

Memcache output:

```
<8 new client connection  
<8 get mynamespace:views/show  
>8 END  
<8 set mynamespace:views/show 0 1457 20499  
>8 STORED  
<9 new client connection  
<9 flush_all
>9 OK  
<9 connection closed.  
<8 get mynamespace:views/show  
>8 END  
<8 set mynamespace:views/show 0 1457 20499  
>8 STORED
```

Comment: Not entirely related, I don't think, but you need to execute `.call(controller_name)` on your `Proc.new{|controller| "..."}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your `expires_in` value inside a proc.

edit: I forgot to mention calling the proc with `.call` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i am getting the error: `RuntimeError (:expires_in must be a number):`

Comment: That doesn't work either :(, gives the same result without the Proc.call

Comment: `caches_action :deals, :expires_in => (3600 - Time.now.to_i % 3600) + 10,
    :cache_path => Proc.new { |controller|
      params = controller.params
      protocol = controller.request.protocol.gsub('://', '')
      key = "complex_key"
      "portal/#{key}"
    }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3865/discussion-between-james-and-pratik-khadloya)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are actually *using* memcached, and not the rails default cache mechanism. You should have something like this in your environment.rb :

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

I had a similar problem while trying to get caching working with :expires_in  I didn't realise that the above was needed. Without it rails defaults to using a FileStore, or a MemoryStore, both of which will happily sit there caching, but ignoring the :expires_in option.

Thanks to [this article on memcached basics by Rob Anderton](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/6/9/rails-2-1-now-with-better-integrated-caching) for helping me figure this out in the end